# Clean up Designer.vb file in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I noticed that my Designer.vb file of one of my forms has **a lot** of controls that aren't even used or visible on my form.  This is probably from copying controls from my other forms.  Is there a way to clean up the Designer.vb file and get rid of all the unused controls?

**UPDATE: This is for a Windows Form project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real solution I see is to copy all the controls into a new form by selecting them in the designer. This way all the not created controls should not follow you to the next form.